# Java - regular expression fixed length split into array

Tags: java, regex

I've seen an example once before, but cannot find it again on how to split a fixed length data stream into an array using Regular expressions.  Is this actually possible, is so, does anyone have a basic example?

```
  08/14       1351 XMGYV4      AOUSC             LTC                        .000          .000 VDPJU01PMP 11AUG14:15:17:05.99
```

I want to store each value into a separated value in an array without using substring.

Comment: `String[] array = s.split( "\\s+" );`

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this case is, that there is no fixed field size for every column.
Hence one needs to match on individual widths, enumerated.

```
    String s = "  08/14       1351 XMGYV4      "
        + "AOUSC             LTC                        .000          .000 "
        + "VDPJU01PMP 11AUG14:15:17:05.99     ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.{7,7})(.{11,11})(.)(.{12,12})(.{18,18})(.*)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); ++i) {
            String g = m.group(i);
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", i, g);
        }
    }
```

This is a listing of groups like `(.{7,7})` of minimal and maximal 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Need to match with regular expression with whitespace character one or more times i.e. "\s"

```
String input = "  08/14       1351 XMGYV4      AOUSC             LTC                        .000          .000 VDPJU01PMP 11AUG14:15:17:05.99     ";
String[] split = input.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Comment: Generally StackOverflow users like seeing some explanation along with a code answer. Can you provide additional information to improve this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider Krayo's solution `String[] array = s.split( "\\s+" );`?